# Modelfunction in STLM

Tags: r, forecast

Hi I want to compute an `STLM` model from the `forecast` package using the `elm` function from the `nnfor` package on the seasonally adjusted time serie.

I can do so by using then `modelfunction` argument.

Let use this time serie:

```
y<- ts(rnorm(300,mean=0,sd=1), start=c(2012,2), frequency=12)

> head(y,10)
             Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun
2012  1.83672399  0.09163453  1.43897758 -0.06213232  0.21279124
             Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov
2012  1.43642897  1.36854342 -0.38119914 -0.94666416  1.41982674
```

It works perfectly with functions from the `forecast` package (ex: `nnetar`)

```
model1 =stlm(y,modelfunction=forecast::nnetar)

model$model
Series: x.sa 
Model:  NNAR(24,1,12)[12] 
Call:   modelfunction(y = x.sa)

Average of 20 networks, each of which is
a 24-12-1 network with 313 weights
options were - linear output units 

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0004526
```

But not from forecasting models from other packages.

```
model2 =stlm(y,modelfunction=nnfor::elm)

> Error in `+.default`(fitted(fit), allseas) : 
  time-series/vector length mismatch
```

Which format we should use for the modelfunction argument ?

Any ideas to help me ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the forecast manual, [Package ‘forecast’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf), you will find the following description of the modelfunction requirements:

"More generally, modelfunction can be any function with first argument a
ts object, that returns an object that can be passed to forecast."

nnfor::elm does take a ts object as its first argument. However, it returns an object of class elm. [Package ‘nnfor’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnfor/nnfor.pdf)

The forecast manual does not list elm as a supported class.

The forecast manual does list several classes supported by forecast:

"baggedModel", "bats", "ets", "Arima", "ar", "fracdiff", "HoltWinters", "lm", "mforecast", "modelAR", "nnetar", "stl", "stlm", "StructTS"